# Meaning of "to a seasonally adjusted"

Tags: word-meaning

I'm confused about the phrase "to a seasonally adjusted". I found it in this text:

> Initial claims for state unemployment benefits declined 10,000 **to a seasonally adjusted** 311,000, the lowest level since November, the Labor Department said on Thursday.

Taken from [Reuters](http://mobile.reuters.com/article/topNews/idUSBREA2Q0XK20140327?irpc=932).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Seasonally adjusted" in statistics means that they have adjusted the figures to take into account the effects of seasonal changed.

In employment, there may be more jobs in certain major sectors during specific months (e.g. tourism in summer). If you would not adjust for those seasonal influences, you could not accurately judge if unemployment goes up or down from one month to the other - or rather, you couldn't judge if that is good or bad.

Often this effect is adjusted for by not comparing to the previous month, but comparing to the *same* month a year earlier. This is not always accurate either though.
For the exact methods of "seasonal adjustment", I guess you should ask a statistician.

Simply said: it means the numbers have been corrected to adjust for some obvious side effects that distract from what you actually want to know.

As a (very much simplified!!) example of "seasonal adjustment":

Say that in June, July and August, because of the tourist season, we have 100,000 people working in the tourist industry on a temporary basis. outside those months, only 20,000 of them have a job.

Now if I compare my unemployment numbers of August with those of September, in August I have 200,000 unemployed people, in September I have 250,000, then I can just look at the numbers and say

> woah! Unemployment went up from by 50 thousand!!

But If I take into account that it is *normal* that every year 80,000 people loose their (temp) job at the end of august, I use the "seasonally adjusted" numbers, and I say:

> Good! The seasonally adjusted figures show that unemployment went *down* by 30,000!

(I would have expected 80,000 people to loose their job because of the end of the tourist season, but only 50,000 did, so that is good news. Somewhere, 30,000 people found new work!)

Of course, this is a *very* simplified scenario!

Comment: Thank you. You mean the " adjust" has to do with the verb " twist" or something like that? To a seasonlly adjusted ? I can not get it. You mean "moderate numbers at the end of a season" ?? Thanks a million in advance.

Comment: "Adjust" means "to change in order to make them more meaningfull". I will add an example to my answer :)

Comment: @user5036 - The term can be written with a hyphen; perhaps that would have been less confusing: _Initial claims for state unemployment benefits declined 10,000 to a seasonally-adjusted 311,000_.

Comment: Yes, it's becoming more common that compound modifiers such as this one are left unhyphenated. I think it makes such sentences harder to read, but this is the price we pay for a living language.